# How to show an element on hover of a sibling?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have been testing CSS selectors. I want to change the display of `p` when I hover the `h3`, so I wrote something like:

```css
div > p{
    display: none;
}

div > h3:hover p{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

but it does not work. What is wrong this? What am I missing?

Comment: @kukkuz You don't have to be the most recent editor to get progress toward the Illuminator badge, just *an* editor. Also, "but" in the question is not the beginning of a sentence, so it shouldn't be capitalized.

Comment: @TylerH didn't intend to be the most recent editor... I thought 'but' must be capitalized.. well, let it be :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `+` [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

```css
div > p {
  display: none;
}

div > h3:hover + p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>HOVER ME</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</div>
```

*to recap*
`h3 p` ...means `p` is descendant of `h3`
`h3 + p` ...means `p` is an immediate next sibling of `h3`

---

If you plan in the near future to have other elements in-between `h3` and `p` than a [General sibling selector `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) would help like in

```css
div > p {
  display: none;
}
div > h3:hover ~ p {    /* notice the general sibling selector */
  display: block;
}

.line{background: red; height: 1px; }
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>HOVER ME</h3>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the *adjacent sibling selector* (`+`) like `div > h3:hover + p`.

See demo below:

```css
div>p {
  display: none;
}

div>h3:hover+p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```